# Update a column based on the primary key present in a different column of the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

| id | topic_id | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | null |
| 2 | null | 1 |

I want to update the second-row topic id based on the id present in the third column(which is a primary key that has topic id as 21)

Comment: You show 2 columns named `id` - this is not possible in a table.

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Comment: You might need to ask your question more clearly. Also you can't have two columns with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
UPDATE table t1
  JOIN table t2 ON t1.id = t2.id2 -- join 2 tables copies according to the relation
SET t2.topic_id = t1.topic_id     -- copy the value into the column
WHERE t2.topic_id IS NULL;        -- update only rows without the value in the column
```

Comment: Code only answers are not that helpful. Do you mind providing some explanation on why this query is the the one that helps them achieve their desired outcome?